# Capture click event on "Copy link address"

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

Is there a way to capture the click event on the context menu "Copy link address"?

I am able to capture the "copy" event but not the "Copy link address".
Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you capturing `copy` event?

Comment: Simply creating a listener

Comment: If you are using something like `document.oncopy`, I guess that won't work. Maybe people can suggest alternatives if you can tell what you are trying to achieve.